# How to use ContextCompat in fragment? It says fragment cannot converted to context

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to use `Contextcompat` and `ActivityCompat` in Fragment but it shows

> error "Error:(49, 50) error: incompatible types: CallFragment cannot be converted to Context" and "Error:(51, 51) error: incompatible types: CallFragment cannot be converted to Activity".

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL); 
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: share your code

Comment: if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL);

            }

Comment: it works in activity but i am trying it in fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL); }
```

use getContext() instead of this in the fragment

Comment: @AhmedKaram plz tell me from where i can know or learn this kind of stuff. Like these structures which differ in condition.

Comment: By experience, my friend every topic or problem you face, try to search for everything around it not only for solving the problem like this https://medium.freecodecamp.org/mastering-android-context-7055c8478a22

Answer (score 1):

```
private Context context;

public Yourclassname(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
}
```

use context instead of "this" and use this below code

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CALL); 
}
```

Comment: where to use this ?

Answer (score 0):

## "this" refers Fragment in your case.

We this clearly means that you need `Context` and `Activity` reference. Since you are using the code inside a Fragment class `this` <-- refers to the Fragment and not to `Activity` or `Context`.

**How to get Context reference?**
get it in the `onAttachMethod(Context context)` method available in Fragment class.

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment{
  
   private Context context;

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Context context)
   {
     this.context = context;
   }
}
```

**How to get Activity reference in Fragment?**

```
getActivity();
```

or

```
(Activity)context;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's late, but I hope someone finds this helpful.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 101);
    }
```